# toString not outputting, simple hierarchy class program

Tags: java, overriding, program-entry-point, tostring, superclass

I have two interfaces and two classes, Order class is parent of CoffeeBagOrder, There is no compiler error it just isn't displaying and I can't see why not

Order class:

```
public abstract class Order implements OrderInterface {
    //variables
    final static double SALES_TAX = 0.1; //not initialised by constructor
    int unitWeight, numberOfUnits;

    public Order() {
        unitWeight=0;
        numberOfUnits=0;
    }

    public Order(int unitWeight, int numberOfUnits) {
        unitWeight=unitWeight;
        numberOfUnits=numberOfUnits;
    }


    public void numberOfItems(int number) {
        numberOfUnits=number;

    }

    public void unitWeight(int weight) {
        unitWeight=weight;

    }



}
```

CoffeeBagOrder class

```
public class CoffeeBagOrder extends Order implements Sales {

    final static double PRICE_PER_KG = 5.55;

    double salesBeforeTax;
    double tax;
    double totalSales;

    public CoffeeBagOrder() {

    }

    public CoffeeBagOrder(int unitWeight, int numberOfUnits) {
        super(unitWeight,numberOfUnits);


    }

    public double calculateSalesBeforeTax() {
        salesBeforeTax= unitWeight*numberOfUnits*5.50;
        return salesBeforeTax;
    }


    public double calculateSalesTax() {
        tax=salesBeforeTax*0.10;
        return tax;
        }



        public double calculateTotalSales() {
        totalSales=salesBeforeTax+tax;
        return totalSales;

    }
    //Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Price before tax: "+calculateSalesBeforeTax()+"\nTax: "+calculateSalesTax()+"\nTotal price: "+calculateTotalSales();
    }


}
```

main

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Tester {
    public static void main (String[] args) {



        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number of bags sold: ");
        int unitWeight=sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter weight of bags in kilograms: ");
        int numberOfUnits=sc.nextInt();

        CoffeeBagOrder customer=new CoffeeBagOrder(unitWeight,numberOfUnits);

        customer.toString();


    }

}
```

I have omitted the interfaces but they are followed accordingly , thanks in advance, also I am unsure if I have efficiently written the constructors as they are both the same?

Comment: I don't see where you are printing it to the console.

Comment: put the customer.toString() call with System.out.println(        customer.toString()); .. currently you are not printing it at all
)

Comment: `System.out.println(customer.toString());`

Comment: Or even: `System.out.println(customer);`, since `println()` will call `toString()` anyway.

Comment: @mumpitz Thanks that works but I am getting 0.0 for all values?

Comment: Use @Override annotation on  toString(), not comment like //Override

Answer (score 0):

Change your Order class constructor like below (check this.):

```
public Order(int unitWeight, int numberOfUnits) {
        this.unitWeight=unitWeight;
        this.numberOfUnits=numberOfUnits;
    }
```

You were not updating class field in constructor! It was assigning the parameter to itself.

And modify toString in CoffeeBagOrder like below (check annotation):

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Price before tax: "+calculateSalesBeforeTax()+"\nTax: "+calculateSalesTax()+"\nTotal price: "+calculateTotalSales();
    }
```

Always use @Override annotation when you intend to override, to take it effect, which is best practice rather than calling toString() explicitly.

And print using

```
System.out.println(customer);
```